# java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "ls -l" (in directory "/home/minecraft/paper/event"): error=2, No such file or directory when executing ls -l

Tags: java, processbuilder

I'm trying to run a simple ls -l command(just for testing). But it somehow can't find the directory.
My code:

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("ls -l");
processBuilder.directory(new File("/home/minecraft/paper/event"));
Process process = processBuilder.start();
```

Error:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "ls -l" (in directory "/home/minecraft/paper/event"): error=2, No such file or directory
```

I tested multiple ways with and without a processbuilder but none of them worked

Thanks

Comment: try `new ProcessBuilder("ls", "-l");`

Comment: You may be relying on environment settings set by bash, so try `new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash", "-c", "ls -l")` or `new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash", "-c", "ls -l /home/minecraft/paper/event")`

Comment: Seems to work, thanks! But how can I run a .sh file?